# Get user installed application list in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

How can I get the list of applications **installed by user only**

so far I have tried to filter system application only but no luck ,this give me list of all application including system apps.

**InstalledApp Class**

```
public  class InstalledApps
{
    public string appName { get; set; }
    public string packageName { get; set; }
    public string icon { get; set; }

}
```

**Getting list**

```
  public List<InstalledApps> getInstalledApp()
    {
        List<InstalledApps> installedApps = new List<InstalledApps>();

        try
        {




            var apps = Android.App.Application.Context.PackageManager.GetInstalledApplications(PackageInfoFlags.MetaData);
            if (apps!=null)
            {
                if (apps.Count>0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < apps.Count; i++)
                    {

                        var info = ctx.PackageManager.GetPackageInfo(apps[i].PackageName, 0);
                        if (isSystemPackage(info)==false)
                        {
                            InstalledApps installapps = new InstalledApps()
                            {
                                appName = apps[i].LoadLabel(Android.App.Application.Context.PackageManager),
                                packageName = apps[i].PackageName,
                                icon = apps[i].LoadIcon(Android.App.Application.Context.PackageManager).ToString()
                            };
                            installedApps.Add(installapps);
                        }

                    }
                    //demo
                    makeToast($"total installed  {apps.Count}");
                    return installedApps;
                }
            }





        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

         //do something with error

        }
        return installedApps;
    }
```

**Checking whether a systme app or not**

```
  private bool isSystemPackage(PackageInfo pkgInfo)
    {
        return ((pkgInfo.ApplicationInfo.Flags & ApplicationInfoFlags.System) != 0);
    }
```

Please help.

Comment: Are you trying to get applications installed in your device?

Comment: yes but installed by user only .

Comment: You can use the package manager and its QueryIntentActivities to ask for only packages that are user launchable and along with your system package filter you can filter those if they are signed by the OEM or a 3rd party, if they are 3rd party than they are pre-installed by the device vendor and thus not "user installed" so you would exclude them from the user launchable list obtain from the package manager